# 'cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG' when saving image

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm getting:

```
OSError at /admin/blog/post/add/
cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
```

error when uploading an image file other than 'jpeg' with Pillow. This is the function I'm using to resize the image:

```
def resize_image(image, size):
    """Resizes image"""

    im = Image.open(image)

    im.convert('RGB')

    im.thumbnail(size)

    thumb_io = BytesIO()

    im.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)

    thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)

    return thumbnail
```

Most solutions to this same error seem to be solved by converting to `'RGB'`, but I'm already doing that in my function except it still keeps giving error when uploading, for example, a .png image. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `im.convert`:

```
im = Image.open(image).convert('RGB')
```

As it is, you're converting to RGB and throwing the result away.